# Help with dumpsys usagestats [ADB]

Tags: adb

I'm totally new to ADB in general and I wanted to try to quantify my app usage throughout a weekly/monthly period. I used the adb shell command **dumpsys usagestats** 
My questions with this is that

1. Can I specify  time range (a period of 30 days) to get the stats for ?
2. What does lastTimeSystem and inactiveTime mean ?

`In-memory daily stats
  timeRange="9/2/2017, 5:30 AM ΓÇô 9/3/2017, 12:48 AM"
    packages
package=com.facebook.katana totalTime="25:35" lastTime="9/2/2017, 11:43 PM" lastTimeSystem="9/3/2017, 12:02 AM" inactiveTime="37:43"`

3. I also wanted to check how much music I stream but spotify usage is 00:00 Is this a bug or is it because the app runs on the background? (I've been streaming for the past 2+ hours)

`package=com.spotify.music totalTime="00:00" lastTime="9/3/2017, 1:28 AM" lastTimeSystem="9/3/2017, 1:28 AM" inactiveTime="01:09"`

4. Is there a way to automate the log saving daily to my storage ?
5. In my earlier searches the dumpsys showed how many times the app was used as well. How can I get it with this adb version ?

Phone details: OnePlus2 on android 6.0.1